# Memcpy vs Memmove - Debug vs Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, c++11, release

I got really strange behavior for my x64 multithreading application.
The execution time in debug mode is faster than in release mode.

I break the problem down and found the issue:
The debug modus optimize (!Note optimition is off!) the memcpy to memmove, which peforms faster. The release mode use still memcpy (!note optimition is on).

This problem slows down my multithreading app in release mode. :(

Anyone any idea?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

#define T_SIZE 1024*1024*2

int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;

    char data[T_SIZE];
    char store[100][T_SIZE];

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        memcpy(store[i % 100], data, T_SIZE);
    }
    // Debug > Release Time 1040 < 1620
    printf("memcpy: %d\n", clock() - start);

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
        memmove(store[i % 100], data, T_SIZE);
    }
    // Debug > Release Time 1040 > 923
    printf("memmove: %d\n", clock() - start);
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, you haven't initialized the arrays. Why are you using `memcpy` and `memmove` anyway?

Comment: Is the performance also different when you use [_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) to allocate the memory? (with a large alignment value)

Comment: Many compilers will choke on a 200 MB stack frame.

Comment: I tried to replicate the results you were getting but couldn't debug time was consistently slower than release. Admittedly I had to reduce the size of the stack allocations from the insane 200MB+ in your example to even get it to run. [See here](http://ideone.com/DAE93o)

Comment: (at)user657267 I need memcpy to copy an tmp data array from a camera to my classes. (at)Wimmel I don´t know how to allocate align? (at)brian beun ing Oh, I think, that is the problem. So I must reserve my needed memory on heap right? Or is there any workaround? (at)sjdow ling I increased my stack reserve to 4 gb but it works not probably like you see. If I decrease it to <200mb it works.. but I need much preallocated memory.

Comment: @user657267: it's perfectly well defined to copy uninitialized `char` values. would be different with `int`, but only formally.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I thought that was `unsigned char` only?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `memmove` would be faster than `memcpy`. In the normal case, they do exactly the same thing; the only difference is that `memmove` has well-defined behavior when the source and target overlap.

Comment: @Viatorus Why do you believe that this memory has to be allocated on the stack? Just out of curiosity I tried giving `data` and `store` `static` storage with the original size to prevent dynamic allocation but to prevent overflowing the stack, optimised release was still faster.

Comment: You must have a pretty old version of VS, one that still omits the _chkstk() probes in the Release build.  It hides the cost of committing and mapping the memory pages, _chkstk() makes that happen *before* you start the timer.  It isn't any faster in true wall clock time.  To compare apples and oranges, you need to move the code in a separate function and attribute it with __declspec(noinline).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The following answer is valid for VS2013 **ONLY**

What we have here is actually stranger than just `memcpy` vs. `memmove`. It's a case of the intrinsic optimization actually slowing things down. The issue stems from the fact that VS2013 inlines memcopy like thus:

```
; 73   :        memcpy(store[i % 100], data, sizeof(data));

    mov eax, 1374389535             ; 51eb851fH
    mul esi
    shr edx, 5
    imul    eax, edx, 100               ; 00000064H
    mov ecx, esi
    sub ecx, eax
    movsxd  rcx, ecx
    shl rcx, 21
    add rcx, r14
    mov rdx, r13
    mov r8d, 16384              ; 00004000H
    npad    12
    $LL413@wmain:
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx], xmm0
    movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+16]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+16], xmm1
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+32]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+32], xmm0
    movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+48]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+48], xmm1
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+64]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+64], xmm0
    movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+80]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+80], xmm1
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+96]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx+96], xmm0
    lea rcx, QWORD PTR [rcx+128]
    movups  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR [rdx+112]
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rcx-16], xmm1
    lea rdx, QWORD PTR [rdx+128]
    dec r8
    jne SHORT $LL413@wmain
```

The issue with this is that we're doing unaligned SSE loads and stores which is actually slower than just using standard C code. I verified this by grabbing the CRTs implementation from the source code included in with visual studio and making a `my_memcpy`

As a way of ensuring that the cache was warm during all of this I had preinitialized all of `data` but the results were telling:

> Warm up took 43ms
>   my_memcpy up took 862ms
>   memmove up took 676ms
>   memcpy up took 1329ms

So why is `memmove` faster? Because it doesn't try to prior optimize because it must assume the data can overlap.

For those curious this is my code in full:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>

namespace {
    const auto t_size = 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 2ULL;
    __declspec(align(16 )) char data[t_size];
    __declspec(align(16 )) char store[100][t_size];
    void * __cdecl my_memcpy(
        void * dst,
        const void * src,
        size_t count
        )
    {
        void * ret = dst;

        /*
        * copy from lower addresses to higher addresses
        */
        while (count--) {
            *(char *)dst = *(char *)src;
            dst = (char *)dst + 1;
            src = (char *)src + 1;
        }

        return(ret);
    }
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    std::mt19937 rd{ std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<short> dist(std::numeric_limits<char>::min(), std::numeric_limits<char>::max());
    auto random = std::bind(dist, rd);

    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    // warms up the cache and initializes
    for (int i = 0; i < t_size; ++i)
            data[i] = static_cast<char>(random());

    auto stop = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Warm up took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "ms\n";

    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
        my_memcpy(store[i % 100], data, sizeof(data));

    stop = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "my_memcpy took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "ms\n";

    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
        memmove(store[i % 100], data, sizeof(data));

    stop = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "memmove took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "ms\n";


    start = steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; ++i)
        memcpy(store[i % 100], data, sizeof(data));

    stop = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "memcpy took " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "ms\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

## Update

While debugging I've found that the compiler did detect that the code I copied from the CRT is `memcpy`, but it links it to the non-intrinsic version in the CRT itself which uses `rep movs` instead of the massive SSE loop above. It seems the issue is ONLY with the intrinsic version.

## Update 2

Per Z boson in the comments it seems that this is all very architecture dependent. On my CPU `rep movsb` is faster, but on older CPUs the SSE or AVX implementation has the potential to be faster. This is per the [Intel Optimization Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html). For unaligned data as `rep movsb` can experience up to a 25% penalty on older hardware. However, that said, it appears that for the vast majority of cases and architectures `rep movsb` will on average beat the SSE or AVX implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. I am very sure, this issue of compiler intrinsic affects other libraries as well. In my project I am using boost and just change memcopy to memmove doesn´t speed it up like the debug version. I mark your answer as right, because it is. Would it be probably save to overwrite memcpy while compiling a library to avoid this slowdown?

Comment: @Viatorus no, `memcopy` is a reserved name and should not be messed with. I would suggest using `std::copy` instead of either, as it allows the runtime to pick the better one (the VC++ runtime uses `memmove`) and is type safe.

Comment: What CPU did you test this on?

Comment: @Zboson Intel Core i7 4600U. Aligned loads with the unaligned instruction have no penalty in SSE past nahalem, so the `__declspec(align(16))` should have worked, but it didn't.

Comment: I would argue that unaligned loads with unaligned instructions don't make much difference either since Nahalem (at least not to explain what I think you're seeing). But since Ivy Bridge `rep movs` is `enhanced rep movs` and is probably the best choice. In any case, builtin memcpy and even the standlib versions are not optimal on Linux or Windows (though they probably are on OSX) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246040/whats-missing-sub-optimal-in-this-memcpy-implementation/26256216#26256216

Comment: @Zboson fair enough, I profiled branch prediction misses and cache misses as well. There weren't any branch prediction misses (or at least not enough to matter). There were cache misses a plenty though which could be explained by non-linear memory access of the SSE `memcpy` once it hits the pipelines (e.g. all the instructions compete for ram access at the same time and may complete out of order, preventing pre-fetch from working correctly). Regardless, it doesn't fundamentally change the fact the the `memcpy` is prematurely optimized.

Comment: @Mgetz: Can OoO execution really break HW prefetching?  I though the prefetchers just looked at which cache line was being read, and didn't care about offset within a line.  So even having your accesses non-monotonic is program order shouldn't be a problem, unless I'm totally wrong.

Comment: @PeterCordes absolutely, if the CPU can tell that the instruction's data dependencies are independent (and thus can be prefetched and executed simultaneously) they can compete. In this case it seems that the CPU is smart enough to detect the lack of dependency, and using register shadowing to speed things up, that in turn is most likely confusing the prefetcher which is seeing non-linear accesses.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: call `memmove`, since it's fastest for your case.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a solution. Because this problem exist not only at memcopy. It was just a working example, if the stack is bigger than 200mb.

Comment: @Viatorus: if you want an answer to a **different question**, then please do post that question and don't refine or generalize or otherwise fundamentally change your question after an answer has been posted.

Comment: Why would `memmove` be faster than `memcpy`?

Comment: because the test case is invalid [`clock_t` is not guaranteed to match wall clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) so the entire thing is invalid. They need to use a monotonic high precision clock if they are going to benchmark these things.

Comment: @Mgetz Could be, but it isn´t. If I increase the iteration count it is noticieable in seconds...