# How to prevent vc++ from emitting calls to memcpy?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vectorization

I'm writing a benchmark program comparing the performance of aligned access and unaligned access.

```
void do_access(int *dest, const int* src, size_t n)
{
  while(n--) {
    *dest++ = *src++;
  }
}
```

The problem is that the code is automatically vectorized and changed to call to `memcpy`, so I cannot compare the difference of aligned/misaligned access.

`GCC` has `-fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns`, but I don't see any relevant option in `Visual Studio`.

I still want auto-vectorization, but not calls to `memcpy`. How do I prevent MSVC++ from doing it?

---

I guess I need to put some background story here. I was like 'unaligned access is UB, so it should always be avoided.', and someone said that 'unaligned access might be faster than aligned access, try to write memcpy and compare it.' I've never seen any article recommending use of unaligned access for performance, so I decided to write memcpy with aligned/unaligned access and compare it.

I thought compiler would generate an instruction which requires alignment and fails to run, and gcc with -O3 did it as I expected. It segfaults. Unfortunately he's insisting that unaligned access is faster in MSVC, but VC replaces everything into a single memcpy so I can not compare the performance with VC. The only thing I need is to disable replacing code with memcpy.

Comment: The optimizer trivially optimizes this code to a single memcpy() call.  You would have to disable it.  Doesn't help much, the compiler expects memcpy and memset to be available, they are also used to initialize and copy structs for example.  Intentionally not taking a dependency on the CRT is only a good way to waste a lot of your time.  And ours.

Comment: Why is auto-vectorization (indeed *any* kind of optimization) needed for the test case you posted here?

Comment: Edited OP. I'm not trying to 'remove' `memcpy`, but want to prevent replacing my code into `memcpy`.

Comment: _"Unfortunately he's insisting that unaligned access is faster in MSVC"_ -- are you sure he is not talking about the under-the-hood-`memcpy` version?

Comment: a few notes: this is dependent on hardware, on nahalem or later unaligned access doesn't have as much penalty as it did on prior hardware, and if the access is aligned but uses the unaligned instruction there is no penalty at all. b) [memmove can actually be faster under certain circumstances](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26959685/332733)

Comment: @CompuChip No, he just keeps saying that 'unaligned access can be an optimization technique', not how-memcpy-is-implemented.

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, there's instructions for unaligned access, and yes, it will help writing assembly, but that doesn't make 'unaligned access in c/c++' well-defined behavior. Compiler still can assume that a pointer is aligned and generate instructions with alignment requirement. I'm trying to make an example of it, and failing with the replaced calls to 'memcpy'.

Comment: Would something like explicit vectorized copy in the loop help?  __m128 buffer = _mm_load_ps(source);           _mm_store_ps(target, buffer);