# Which technologies is __movsb belong to?

Tags: visual-c++, intrinsics

About this function **__movsb** :

link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhta9830.aspx

I wish to know which technologies it is belong to (Such as **SSE** , **AVX**)

link : https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

I couldn't find it (__movsb) from the website , anyone know ?

Comment: Goes all the way back to the original 8086.  Don't use it, memcpy/memmove can do a better job.

Comment: memcpy is slower than it, I need a faster speed.

Comment: extra-fast `rep movsb` is a new feature with IvyBridge.  Before that, it was better to use `rep movsq`.  [The enhances movsb / stosb feature is called ERMSB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246040/whats-missing-sub-optimal-in-this-memcpy-implementation)