# For aligned memcpy and memset REP MOVSD and REP STOSD vs temporal and non-temproray ymm / zmm registers

Tags: assembly, x86-64, memcpy, memset

I have seen a few very informative posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246040/whats-missing-sub-optimal-in-this-memcpy-implementation/26256216#comment41203823_26256216) discussing the merits of difference approach for copying / setting memory.

All of the posts go into detail about the pros and cons of REP MOVSD in a variety of settings, though I found where discussing the topic in too generic a setting to actual come to any definitive answers.

So for x86_64 skylake I am curious about the following scenarios:

Assume for all scenarios ***both src and dst are page aligned***

- ***Copying 16384 bytes of data***

  - Comparing `REP MOVSD`, `ymm blocks`, `zmm blocks`
- ***Copying 2 Gibabytes of data***

  - Comparing `REP MOVSD`, `ymm blocks w/ VMOVNTDQ`, `zmm blocks w/ VMOVNTDQ`
- ***Setting 16384 bytes of data***

  - Comparing `REP STOSD`, `ymm blocks`, `zmm blocks`
- ***Setting 2 Gibabytes of data***

  - Comparing `REP STOSD`, `ymm blocks w/ VMOVNTDQ`, `zmm blocks w/ VMOVNTDQ`

Based the glibc imlementation of [memcpy](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S) and [memset](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memset-vec-unaligned-erms.S)

It seems SIMD register for `memcpy` and `REP STOSD` for both of the memset cases.

I am curious if there are any hard recommendations for these scenarios (and to understand better why they are recommendations).

Thank you.

Edit: One of the reasons I am making this post is that the other posts didn't seem to discuss `AVX512`.

Comment: Note that the assumption on page alignment is a very dangerous one as buffers are most often not page aligned and a lot of time is spent getting to an aligned state.  Also consider that most buffers copied are actually less than about 100 bytes long.

Comment: Have you benchmarked these scenarios strategies?

Comment: For very large transfers it might be better to have a DMA controller perform the copying.

Comment: @fuz yeah, but I think the other psots where pretty clear about those cases.

Comment: @EOF Are you sure? DMA usually involves transfer away from the fast memory controller to some DMA engine on some bus and can be a lot slower than raw memory bandwidth.

Comment: @fuz I expect that depends heavily on the specific architecture. However: 1) while the DMA engine copies memory, the CPU can keep computing, especially if you make an asynchronous memory copy abstraction and 2) even if you're doing a synchronous copy, the DMA engine will be vastly simpler (even for equivalent bandwidth) than a general-purpose CPU, which implies much lower power consumption and consequently heat. If you're blocked on memory bandwidth you can use the time to reduce CPU temperature and open up thermal headroom for boosting the clock as soon as you're compute bound again.

Comment: @EOF on the other hand, this'll certainly mean that all your cache needs to be invalidated, slowing down any transfers back from memory.

Comment: As I said, "For very large transfers". For those your cache will not help *anyway*, and a DMA transfer can avoid polluting your cache (otherwise you would need explicitly non-caching instructions for this) so your working set isn't completely evicted. Wiping out your caches (and TLB!) down to physical memory, beyond LLC with a large `memcpy()` will make your performance suck for quite a while afterwards.

Comment: @fuz Whether you need to explicitly flush caches for DMA to work correctly depends on the architecture again. Some architectures have DMA engines that respect cache coherence, so for those you don't need to do anything special. Others, you only need to clean the cache, rather than flush it. Only on truly programmer-hostile architectures will the caches have to be completely flushed, and even then you probably don't have to flush physically tagged/physically indexed caches unless the architecture is actively malicious. Even then, see my previous comment.

Comment: @EOF that's not what I mean; after DMA is done, the data that was just DMA-copied is no longer in cache and has to be reloaded from memory.  That can be expensive.  I am of course assuming that cache coherency is somehow dealt with.  CPU-based memory copy procedures can avoid this.

Comment: @fuz, check out Intel DSA [https://01.org/blogs/2019/introducing-intel-data-streaming-accelerator https://01.org/blogs/2019/introducing-intel-data-streaming-accelerator] (unfortunately not available yet). It can write to cache or not under software control.

Comment: @EOF, you may also be interested in my previous comment.